# TypeScript coded menu and Grid not displaying correctly

Tags: css, angular, grid

So I am trying to create a menu which derives its elements from code. This is to make it much easier to add new elements, and/or in the future put the menu items into a database to make them easier to edit and add to without recompiling.

I want the menu to look like this:

[image: The intended design]

However the behavior is currently not working very well, i.e.

[image: The current behavior of the menu]

I have created a stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ejlj7n?file=src/app/app.module.ts

I have tried a bunch of stuff, such as creating a sub grid for each hover section, setting width for items, rearranging what is listed in each grid section etc- but im not sure what else I can do. The erratic nature clearly comes from the fact that elements are moving when hovered over.

Another issue is that submenus are opening up in the same column as their master, not spanning the entire width of the grid, which I suspect is because those divs are (by necessity to create a HTML/CSS only menu system) sub-divs of their owning menu item.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I have given up on the pure pure css version of this and with a little code made it work. Im not sure still why it didnt work before but what I did was to reiterate over the menu items, and on hover over a menu item update a variable in the code which allows the sub items to show, so all the [unstyled] code was:

```
menuHoverId: number;
menuMidHoverId: number;
menuHover(id: number) { this.menuHoverId = id; }
menuMidHover(id: number) { this.menuMidHoverId = id; }
```

and then in the HTML I am reiterating over each section each time and testing against those variables. As I hover over a parent menu item I reassign the id in the array I am searching for:

```
    <header>
        <div class="grid-container">
           <div class="title">Test/Blocks/etc</div>

           <div class="top-menu">
              <div class="top-menu-item" *ngFor="let section of menuList; let i = index" (mouseover)="menuHover(i)">{{ section.title }}</div>
           </div>

           <div class="mid-menu">
              <span *ngFor="let section of menuList; let i = index">
                 <span *ngIf="menuHoverId===i">
                    <div class="mid-menu-item" *ngFor="let link of section.items; let o = index" (mouseover)="menuMidHover(o)">{{ link.name }}</div>
                 </span>
              </span>
           </div>
           
           <div class="bottom-menu">
              <span *ngFor="let section of menuList; let i = index">
                 <span *ngIf="menuHoverId===i">
                    <span *ngFor="let link of section.items; let o = index">
                       <span *ngIf="menuMidHoverId===o">
                          <div class="bottom-menu-item" *ngFor="let subsim of link.subItems; let t = index">
                             {{ subsim.name }}
                          </div>
                       </span>
                    </span>
                 </span>
              </span>
           </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

and then the css is straightforward grid layout:

```
.grid-container {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr;
   grid-template-rows: repeat(4, auto);
   gap: 4px 0px;
   grid-template-areas:
        "title"
        "top-menu"
        "mid-menu"
        "bottom-menu";
   }
   .title { grid-area: title; }
   .top-menu { grid-area: top-menu; }
   .top-menu-item { display: inline-block; }
   .mid-menu { grid-area: mid-menu; }
   .mid-menu-item { display: inline-block; }
   .bottom-menu { grid-area: bottom-menu; }
   .bottom-menu-item { display: inline-block; }
```

It works smoothly - not the solution I was looking for but its the solution I can be bothered with :)

Thanks to all those who looked at the problem!